# Can't order double digit numbers in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to sort the numbers in my database to print out five high scores for a game. The problem is when I try to sort I either get a sort by the first digit or the double digit numbers don't get printed out to my high score. The mess is in the deleteProduct() method.

DBHandler class

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS) <= 4){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    else{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        deleteProduct();
        db.close();
    }
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void addButtonClicked(String highscore1){
    Products product = new Products(highscore1);
    addProduct(product);
    updateDatabase();
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void updateDatabase(){
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText.setText(dbString);
}

//delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM products WHERE _id NOT IN"+
                //only reading first digit of double digit numbers
               //" (SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY  productname DESC LIMIT 5)");
            //this runs but isnt putting double digit scores into the high score textView
            " (SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY  length(productname), productname DESC LIMIT 5)");


}


//print out the database as a string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";


    //Cursor point to location in your results
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" DESC");
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();

    }


    db.close();
    return dbString;

}
```

Comment: Since your field is a TEXT, instead of being a NUMERIC type (due to poor database design skills), you need to explicitly pad the 1 digit "numbers" with a leading 0. Otherwise, in **character sorting**, 10 is lower than 2. Whereas 02 is lower than 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY productname DESC LIMIT 5
```

This query sorts by the values in the `productname` column. If these values are strings, the sort order is defined by the first character.

You should store numbers instead.

If you cannot change your database, convert the values into numbers before using them for sorting:

```
SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY CAST(productname AS NUMBER) DESC LIMIT 5
```